# Finding specific elements in a recordset, classic ASP

Tags: html, asp.net, recordset

i'm trying to extract specific elements from a "select" statement in order to fill in a table on a website. I will be using Classic ASP.

say for example, my select statement below returns these values;

Name     ID
Alex    Alex123

Now, on my webpage, i want the table to look something like this,

Name    Nickname       ID      Address
Alex  "input field"   Alex123  "input field"

In my html code i'm expecting to do something like this. How can i do this?

```
<tr>
 <td> "some code to extract "Alex" from the recordset"</td>
 <td> <input blalbalba> </td>
 <td> "some code to extract "Alex123" from the recordset"</td>
 <td> <input blabalba> </td>
</tr>
```

Below is my connection string and my select statement.

```
Set Con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=YOONGTAT\SQLEXPRESS;Database=testing;User ID=sa;password=1234"
Con.open

set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open "Select * from dbo.exampletable where user_name like '%" & Request.Form("employeeName[]")(i) & "%' and user_id like '%" & Request.Form("employeeId[]")(i) & "%'" , con
```

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405736/classic-asp-to-pull-data-from-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop through the recordset, pulling out whatever field values you are interested in and printing them in-line with the appropriate HTML. Something like this should do the trick:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Nickname</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<%
  rs.Open "Select * from dbo.exampletable where user_name like '%" & Request.Form("employeeName[]")(i) & "%' and user_id like '%" & Request.Form("employeeId[]")(i) & "%'" , con
  do while not rs.BOF and not rs.EOF
    Response.Write("<tr>")
    Response.Write("<td>" & rs("NameFieldName") & "</td>")
    Response.Write("<td><input type=""text"" id=""nickname""></td>")
    Response.Write("<td>" & rs("IdFieldName") & "</td>")
    Response.Write("<td><input type=""text"" id=""address""></td>")
    Response.Write("</tr>")
    rs.MoveNext
  loop
  rs.Close
%>
```

Sorry if my syntax is a little off. It's been a long time since I did Classic ASP. :) You'll have to change the database field names to whatever the real names are, and I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for with the input fields, so adjust accordingly, but this should be enough to get you going.